# searching for facebook pages with fb open graph API using keyword and defined country

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to search for list of pages for keyword 'clinic'
I need all pages to be from specific country
currently, I'm using this:

```
search?q=clinic&type=page&fields=id,name,location{country}
```

I got some local pages but also some other foreign pages, is there a way to define the country in the search query command?

Comment: No, there is not. At most you could try searching for _places_ around a certain location.

Comment: Yes, I searched for places, but it gives much fewer results, so you think no more options with the type page that may narrow my search results?

Comment: No, no more options. You’ll have to do the filtering by country on your end.